# RavenDB auto tmpindex and manual index

Tags: c#, indexing, ravendb

When I created an index with the following class

```
public class TokenIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Token> {
    public TokenIndex() {
        Map = tokens => from token in tokens
                        select new { token.Guid };
        Index(x => x.Guid, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

it produced the following index

```
docs.Tokens.Select(token => new {
    Guid = token.Guid
})
```

But when I let Raven create an tmpindex it looked like this

```
from doc in docs.Tokens
select new { Guid = doc.Guid }
```

Are there any performance differences between thies two in the longrun? Or is it only 2 ways to write the same thing?

Comment: Is there anything unanswered? Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler turns the latter into the former. There is no way for RavenDB to even differentiate between the two. So there *cannot be* a performance difference.